# Strange error when adding UIFont to styling dictionary (NSAttributedString)

Tags: xcode, swift, nsdictionary, nsattributedstring, uifont

I am trying to add a custom font to my attributed string. But then I get this strange error (Version 6.3 (6D570))
[image]

When I instead a system font it works.
Any Idea whats wrong?
[image]

Here is the function to play with.

```
   func generateAttributedString(labelSettings: LabelSettings) -> NSAttributedString {

        let title = labelSettings.fullTitle()
        let font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-UltraLight", size: 22)

        var attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: title,
            attributes: [
                NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor(),
                NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFontOfSize(22)
            ]
        )

        let rangeToDecorate = (title as NSString).rangeOfString(labelSettings.details)

        attributedText.addAttributes(
            [ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.titleColor()],
            range: rangeToDecorate)
        return attributedText
    }
```

Comment: `UIFont()` returns an *optional* which needs to be unwrapped ...

Comment: You were right. Thanks. I must remind my self and code on normal hours.